# setting up virtual hosts in ampps

Tags: ampps

I am trying to create a virtual host in ammps under windows 8, the document root should be under an external hard drive F: directory this is my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    <Directory "{$path}/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        allow from All
    </Directory>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost 127.0.0.1
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "{$path}/www/cgi-bin/"
    DocumentRoot "{$path}/www"
    ErrorLog "{$path}/apache/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "{$path}/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "F:/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        allow from All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot "F:/www"
    ServerName site1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is my hosts file

```
127.0.0.1           site1.com
127.0.0.1           site2.com
127.0.0.1           site3.com
127.0.0.1           site4.com
127.0.0.1           site5.com
```

when I type site1.com , I get the default virtual server instead, what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change  the ip address from * to 127.0.0.1  this should fix  it

hope that helps !

it should look like this

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
<Directory "{$path}/www">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost 127.0.0.1
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "{$path}/www/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "{$path}/www"
ErrorLog "{$path}/apache/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "{$path}/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "F:/www">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "F:/www"
ServerName site1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where was your change made? Where was `*` changed to `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 7):

its better to create Virtual host in AMPPS via its admin panel

```
http://localhost/ampps/
```

add domain:
[image]
and justdo it
[image]

Comment: nice suggestion. I dont know why people choose complicated way, if simple is available there.

Comment: Probably because it doesn't really work on all machines. I have a macbook pro and the way mentioned here just doesn't work.

Comment: If GUI is rendering on Mac then their should not any issue in it. Check error logs their should be permissions problem to generate the file.

Comment: true, not working.

Comment: This is the best answer. AMPPS is somewhat different from other Apache pack.

Answer (score 0):

1 login http://localhost/ampps/
2 add domain
3 add to file Ampps\conf\httpd.conf line #530

```
    <VirtualHost ssd.co>
<Directory "H:/WWW/ssd.co/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost ssd.co
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "{$path}/www/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "H:/WWW/ssd.co/"
ErrorLog "{$path}/apache/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "{$path}/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```