# 2 Laravel applications, 1 server

Tags: php, laravel, ampps

So I have a server that I need to run 2 Laravel applications: 1 api, 1 web client.  With the way routing works I had to set the API public directory as the document root in the Apache config.

This then prevents the web client from working correcting.  Obviously I'm messing something up because I shouldn't need 2 Apache instances or servers.  And I don't want the web client folder structure to mesh with the API folder structure.  Right now it looks like this:

```
-ampps
  -otherAmppsFolders
  -www
    -api
      -otherLaravelFolders
      -public  [DocumentRoot set here]
      -moreLaravelFolders
    -myWebSite
      -otherLaravelFolders
      -public  [Cannot access this then]
      -moreLaravelFolders
```

FYSA: I am using Ampps on Windows.

Comment: you are using what? windows? if yes, do you use xampp? wamp? if not? what are you using?

Comment: Sorry, only added a tag.  Ampps on Windows.

Comment: well, i think you need to enable vhosts. quick search led me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455403/add-virtual-host-for-localhost-ampps