# Ampps virtual host not working in latest macos catalina

Tags: php, macos, virtualhost, macos-catalina, ampps

After creation of successful virtualhost domain in ampps, not able to view the site properly. It just shows cgi-bin folder and won't target to the default index.php | index.html.

### On amppsresumebuilder, only cgi-bin is seen and no other contents.

[image]

[image]

### The status of the ampps is as follows:

### [image]

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found this to solve my issue:
[Add Virtual Host for Localhost Ampps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455403/add-virtual-host-for-localhost-ampps#22455464)

Adding the domain name to the virtual host line resolved the issue for me.